# Unable to export default solution in dynamics 365, Error: "Record is unavailable"

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I am trying to export the default solution on my Dynamics 365 production instance and it is giving me the error "Record is unavailable". I am logged in as the administrator. All customizations are published.

[image]

Comment: what does that 'Show technical details' says? Paste the full log in question

Comment: It doesn't show anything. The "Download log file" button is disabled.

Comment: There’s a blue hyperlink, you see?

Comment: On premise? Anything on trace, event log? Remove 2013 & 2011 tags.

Comment: Dynamics 365 online. No event logs. Nothing on clicking the hyperlink. No details.

Comment: Hi Mani, the suggestion is to not touch the default soulution, most of the time that method fails ( i think is related to some entities/properties that are managed and not editable ). Will it be acceptable for you to create a solution an cherry pick the entities?